# Error deployApp when uploading bundle for application - shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying for the first time to deploy an App on ShinyApp.io and I manage some issues do it.

I ran the command :

```
>shinyapps::deployApp('C:/Users/Karim/Documents/test')
```

And the following message appeared :

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 66633...
Error in digest::digest(file.path(appDir, file), algo = "md5", file = TRUE) : 
  The file does not exist: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\RtmpugxfSW\fileabc59e7164e/..
```

I noted that the file mentioned (C:\Windows\Temp...) does exist and contains ui and server files. Yet I don't know which file is missing.

I tried to see if there was no similar cases in the forum by I didn't find similar mistakes. 
If anyone know how to solve this error or guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Karim.

Comment: I have exactly the same issues when deploying my App.
I put all my file (`ui.R; server.R`; etc.) in the same folder and use the same code as @Karim.

Please if someone can help !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative rather than absolute paths, 
https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/229848967-Why-does-my-app-work-locally-but-not-on-shinyapps-io-

Comment: You might want to add a bit of [context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). Otherwise this might be considered a [link-only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).