# Error: file does not exist. Uploading shiny app to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Multiple users have posted the same specific issue (link below) but there are currently no posted answers. Shiny App runs fine locally but will not upload to shinyapps.io. The .csv files are in a folder within the working dir called "data". I'm having the same "Uploading bundle error" issue. If I go to the link that it asks to update, I get a 404 not found error

```
read.csv("./data/mydata.csv")
deployApp()

Preparing to deploy application...
Update application currently deployed at
Update application currently deployed at
https://MyUsername.shinyapps.io/MyApp/? [Y/n] Y
DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 150705...
Error: The file does not exist: C:\windows\TEMP\Rtmpc5JO0a\file29....
```

[Similar question with no answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436679/error-deployapp-when-uploading-bundle-for-application-shinyapp)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setwd()` to set the working directory to the app folder. No need to run rstudio as admin.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are using Rstudio to deploy your app. I had similar problem and it got resolved once I run Rstudio as administrator.